# Table field that accept only numbers in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How to make a table field to accept only numbers.
If it is any other (key), it should not display it in that field.
IS that possible? If so please let me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I must admit I have not tested this, but the default `JTable` has an inner class `NumberEditor` (javax.swing.JTable.NumberEditor). So I assume that when your `TableModel` correctly indicates [the column class is a number extension](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getColumnClass%28int%29), the default editor will be one that only accepts numbers

If the default editor is not what you are looking for, you can write your own editor, for example by using a `JFormattedTextField` as editor. See the [Swing table tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for more information. This tutorial contains a section about a custom editor which should get you started if you want to write your own editor.

Comment: @trashgod it seems you have sample code for almost every problem that is posted here. I am surprised you even remember all your snippets

Comment: Ixnay; I'm using SO for off-site backup, but no one must know! :-)